# Qbs: run googletests while building arm target

Tags: arm, stm32, qbs

I use qbs (inside Qt Creator) to build my STM32 project and upload it using the baremetal plugin.
And it works great.

But I also have tests for the libraries used in my firmware. And for sure I would like to build and run them.

Now I need to prepare another project which is configured for Windows/Linux/MacOS to run tests. So I need to switch between projects to test or to debug on my board.

Is there is a possibility to combine 2 subprojects with different architecture targets in one qbs project?

Any bits of advice or tricks highly appreciated. Thank you.